# Upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, bios

I need upgrade my notebook with Ubuntu 12.04, however the BIOS is locked.
I am unsure what is possible problems can happens if I try upgrade my Ubuntu to the version 14.04 on the system with locked BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry I cannot comment yet)

There are a few options to break a bios:
http://www.wikihow.com/Break-a-BIOS-Password

Obviously a fresh install is recommended.
Personally, I had a bad experience upgrading from 12 to 14.
Some suggest to upgrade to 13 and then to 14.